# How Connect to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I need to **access** my **database** which is located in University **central server**. University gave me the **ip address**  and also **root access** and the **password**. *I don't Have the port address*,i know to connect to a database with port address like this,i Used this Connection String to connect multiple computers and it works,but Want to connect my database through the univercity server

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1,2222\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Temp_project;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

Comment: SQL Server is usually on port 1433 but you can omit the port if it is on the standard.

Comment: that server is a local server and it has no ports opened my program is working only under the university network connection.it should not be opend to the outside

Comment: i just need a way to access to the  database and also without port address

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, and using terms like "local server" and "without port" don't help. Do you mean you want to connect to your university's database server when taking your laptop or code home? You probably can't, unless you use a VPN to connect to your school's network.

Comment: I don't know the instance name of your Uni's server nor the exact IP address so I can't tell you what it is. [Look here for guidance](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/). If you are on lthe local network (10.10,x.x) then you might be able to discover the server in the connection dialog of SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: no no , i already connected to the server and i created the database it is working,but to connect to the server through the c# it need the port address but they didn't gave me  any ,thay said that that server is local so no need of port address to connect  ,and the problem is i don't know how to connect  without port address

Comment: @KãvîñdūTîssêrã just take the port out. Instead of `10.10.x.x,1433` use `10.10.x.x`.

Comment: _"it need the port address"_ - what makes you think so? Did someone tell you that, or are you paraphrasing an error message? "The port address" is not a valid term.

Comment: Try this: `Data Source=(local)`

Comment: i used to connect database with port address that's why  i'm saying like that,and i don't know another way

Comment: thank you for the help but i couldn't find out if those working .because i'm not in the university,so tomorrow i can try those code but until i can't ,i'm sorry

Comment: Stop using the term "port address" and ask the question you actually want answered. Simply use the format as [@Crowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300689/how-connect-to-a-database-which-is-located-in-a-local-server-in-c-sharp#comment93482486_53300689) said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example connection string that will work with MS Sql database:

```
"Server=tcp:<domain/IP>,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist SecurityInfo=False;UserID=<myUser>;Password=<myPassword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Addressing your info that u got 10.10.X.X Ip and u dont know mucha about networking - If u want to reach IP like this (10.10.X.X), you need to be in same network with the PC where database is located. Simply said - you have to be or in the university network or use a VPN connection.

Comment: yes that's right, you have understood my problem but is that 1433 is  a port address because i don't have ip address

Comment: Yes, 1433 is a port in my connection string, and this is default port under which sql chooses to work.  If port is not provided in connection string, like this:

  "Server=tcp:<domain/IP>;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist SecurityInfo=False;UserID=<myUser>;Password=<myPassword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

The 1433 will be used anyway.